# General solution of the Multiplicative symmetry equation $f(xf(y))=f(f(x)y)$ in nonabelian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, functional-equations

As we know, the functional equation $f(xf(y))=f(f(x)y)$ was completely solved in abelian groups (by J. G. Dhombres, Solution... $f(x\ast
f(y))=f(y\ast f(x))$, Aequationes Math. 15 (1977), 173--193, doi:[10.1007/BF01835648](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01835648)).

But in the book "Functional Equations in Several Variables" (J. Aczel and J. Dhombres), they [mentioned that](https://books.google.com/books?id=8EWnEh18rVgC&pg=PA329):

it has been generalized for nonabelian groups but *with additional assumptions*
concerning $f$, and the problem is open in general (also in abelian quasigroups).

Now, my question is:

(1) What is the additional assumptions (on $f$) in nonabelian groups?

(2) Any progress in abelian quasi-groups?

(3) Are there any papers or books regarding the problems?

Comment: See a related recent paper here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00010-019-00663-8